# Why this Kernel Perceptron implementation is taking infinite time to run?

Tags: python, matplotlib, runtime-error, runtime, contour

I am trying to apply kernel perceptron algorithm on a dataset. So I have written the code and I run it. It is working properly but when I try to plot the decision boundary,It is taking infinite time to run. Here I am attaching the code

```
# All the import statements

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import random
import pylab as pl



#Kernel Perceptron class where I wrote fit and predict functions

def linear_kernel(x1, x2):
    return np.dot(x1, x2)

def polynomial_kernel(x, y, p=3):
    return (1 + np.dot(x, y)) ** p

class KernelPerceptron(object):
def __init__(self, kernel=linear_kernel, T=1):
    self.kernel = kernel
    self.T = T

def fit(self, X, y):
    n_samples, n_features = X.shape
    #np.hstack((X, np.ones((n_samples, 1))))
    self.alpha = np.zeros(n_samples, dtype=np.float64)

    # Gram matrix
    K = np.zeros((n_samples, n_samples))
    for i in range(n_samples):
        for j in range(n_samples):
            K[i,j] = self.kernel(X[i], X[j])

    for t in range(self.T):
        for i in range(n_samples):
            if np.sign(np.sum(K[:,i] * self.alpha * y)) != y[i]:
                self.alpha[i] += 1.0

    # Support vectors
    sv = self.alpha > 1e-5
    ind = np.arange(len(self.alpha))[sv]
    self.alpha = self.alpha[sv]
    self.sv = X[sv]
    self.sv_y = y[sv]
    print (len(self.alpha), n_samples)

def project(self, X):
    y_predict = np.zeros(len(X))
    for i in range(len(X)):
        s = 0
        for a, sv_y, sv in zip(self.alpha, self.sv_y, self.sv):
            s += a * sv_y * self.kernel(X[i], sv)
        y_predict[i] = s
    return y_predict

def predict(self, X):
    X = np.atleast_2d(X)
    n_samples, n_features = X.shape
    #np.hstack((X, np.ones((n_samples, 1))))
    return np.sign(self.project(X))




#Testing on the dataset I have

data = pd.read_csv("Dataset_1_Team_35.csv").to_numpy()
points = []
labels = []
i = 0
while i<1000 :
    l = []
    l.append(data[i][0])
    l.append(data[i][1])
    points.append(l)
    labels.append(data[i][2])
    i+=1
X = np.array(points)
y = np.array(labels)
# print(type(X),type(y),len(X),len(y))
print(X.shape,y.shape)
xtr,xts,ytr,yts = train_test_split(X,y,test_size = 0.2)
print(xtr.shape,ytr.shape)
clf =KernelPerceptron(polynomial_kernel , 2)
clf.fit(xtr,ytr)
pred = clf.predict(xtr)
val = accuracy_score(pred,ytr)
print(val)




#Code for plotting the decision boundary


def make_meshgrid(x, y, h=.02):
x_min, x_max = x.min() - 1, x.max() + 1
y_min, y_max = y.min() - 1, y.max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
return xx, yy

def plot_contours(ax, clf, xx, yy, **params):
Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
out = ax.contourf(xx, yy, Z, **params)
return out

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
X0, X1 = xtr[:, 0], xtr[:, 1]
xx, yy = make_meshgrid(X0, X1)
plot_contours(ax, clf, xx, yy, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, alpha=1) #line taking infinite time to load
ax.scatter(X0, X1, c=ytr, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, s=20, edgecolors='k')
ax.set_title(title)
```

So I tried to debug and I tried to run it line by line on jupyter notebook and found out that the line

```
plot_contours(ax, clf, xx, yy, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, alpha=1)
```

is taking infinite time to run? When I tried run the algorithm on another dataset it is taking less time to run.

Can anyone help me with this?

If any one wants dataset it is a simple data set with 1000 entries(points and their corresponding labels) in it. [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YDl2WjZT_ximaRgP93W7iivBYK6tz4BA/view) to the data set.

Comment: Are you sure it takes infinite time? Have you measured it?

Comment: Infinite in the sense, I left it runnong from morning to night and it is still running, So I assumed it as infinite time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not taking infinite time, it's just that in training you are fitting 800 data points and then predicting on 800 data points, but when you are creating a plot, you have 28889748 data points, hence it is taking so much time.

to reduce this much data points while creating a plot, I suggest two things:
1) normalize the data using standard scalar
2) increase the step size when creating the mesh grid (like from 0.02 to 0.2) in the make_meshgrid function

here is the modified code:

```
# All the import statements

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import random
import pylab as pl



#Kernel Perceptron class where I wrote fit and predict functions

def linear_kernel(x1, x2):
    return np.dot(x1, x2)

def polynomial_kernel(x, y, p=3):
    return (1 + np.dot(x, y)) ** p

class KernelPerceptron(object):
    def __init__(self, kernel=linear_kernel, T=1):
        self.kernel = kernel
        self.T = T

    def fit(self, X, y):
        n_samples, n_features = X.shape
        #np.hstack((X, np.ones((n_samples, 1))))
        self.alpha = np.zeros(n_samples, dtype=np.float64)

        # Gram matrix
        K = np.zeros((n_samples, n_samples))
        for i in range(n_samples):
            for j in range(n_samples):
                K[i,j] = self.kernel(X[i], X[j])

        for t in range(self.T):
            for i in range(n_samples):
                if np.sign(np.sum(K[:,i] * self.alpha * y)) != y[i]:
                    self.alpha[i] += 1.0

        # Support vectors
        sv = self.alpha > 1e-5
        ind = np.arange(len(self.alpha))[sv]
        self.alpha = self.alpha[sv]
        self.sv = X[sv]
        self.sv_y = y[sv]
        print (len(self.alpha), n_samples)

    def project(self, X):
        y_predict = np.zeros(len(X))
        print(f'data points len: {len(X)}')
        for i in range(len(X)):
            # print('dbg3.2')
            s = 0
            for a, sv_y, sv in zip(self.alpha, self.sv_y, self.sv):
                s += a * sv_y * self.kernel(X[i], sv)
            y_predict[i] = s
        return y_predict

    def predict(self, X):
        X = np.atleast_2d(X)
        n_samples, n_features = X.shape
        #np.hstack((X, np.ones((n_samples, 1))))
        return np.sign(self.project(X))




#Testing on the dataset I have

data = pd.read_csv("Dataset_1_Team_35.csv").to_numpy()
points = []
labels = []
i = 0
while i<1000 :
    l = []
    l.append(data[i][0])
    l.append(data[i][1])
    points.append(l)
    labels.append(data[i][2])
    i+=1
X = np.array(points)
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X)
X = scaler.transform(X)
y = np.array(labels)
# print(type(X),type(y),len(X),len(y))
print(X.shape,y.shape)
xtr,xts,ytr,yts = train_test_split(X,y,test_size = 0.2)
print(xtr.shape,ytr.shape)
clf = KernelPerceptron(polynomial_kernel , 2)
clf.fit(xtr,ytr)
print(f'xtr: {xtr}')
pred = clf.predict(xtr)
val = accuracy_score(pred,ytr)
print(val)




#Code for plotting the decision boundary


def make_meshgrid(x, y, h=.02):
    x_min, x_max = x.min() - 1, x.max() + 1
    y_min, y_max = y.min() - 1, y.max() + 1
    # print(f'xmin: {x_min}, xmax: {x_max}, ymin: {y_min}, ymax: {y_max}')
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
    return xx, yy

def plot_contours(ax, clf, xx, yy, **params):
    # print(f'np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]: {np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]}')
    Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
    out = ax.contourf(xx, yy, Z, **params)
    return out

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
X0, X1 = xtr[:, 0], xtr[:, 1]
xx, yy = make_meshgrid(X0, X1, 0.2)
plot_contours(ax, clf, xx, yy, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, alpha=1) #line taking infinite time to load
ax.scatter(X0, X1, c=ytr, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, s=20, edgecolors='k')
ax.set_title('title')
plt.show()
```

here is the resulting plot:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. May I know why it has 28889748 points while plotting? And also could you please tell me what is the use of argument 'T' when creating a Kernel Perceptron( I got the code for kernel perceptron from github and I don't understand the use of T).

Comment: from your data, suppose you get some 800 data points, then max and min of those will be like this:
xmin: -88.24956259999999, xmax: 64.2288819, ymin: -18.0937485, ymax: 58.6594335.

then when you do : np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), with h = 0.02, essentially you are creating a list of numbers from x_min till x_max with step of 0.02.

So in this case np.arange(x_min, x_max, h) will have 7624 points, and np.arange(y_min, y_max, h) will have 3838 points.

Comment: then in np.meshgrid you are essentially creating a mesh of these two lists, hence you will 7624*3838 datapoints = 29260912.

since the 800 points you selected initially are random, this number can slightly deviate from one run to another.

Comment: I am not sure of the use of T, can you give a link, from where you got this code?